# How to force Teradata parser to understand the join

Tags: sql, database, view, teradata

I would like your help for the next issue. It is a real problem, but I will present you like an example.

I have a view which is composed as below

```
viewa =
sel * from
(
calendar_dim
inner join
(
sel * from table_a
inner join table_b
union all
sel * from table_c
inner join table_D
)
on...
)
```

All the tables, table_a table_b table_c table_d have the same pi and partition columns (the 1st partition level is at the date), stats are up to date.

My question is the following:

If I will try to do a query such as

```
sel *
  from viewa
 where cal_Date = '2013-05-31'
-->> the explain plan works perfect. It takes only one partition from each table and produce the result.
```

The same happens with multiple date , /......where cal_Date in ('2013-05-31','','',.......)
(it takes the correct number of partitions ).

But, if I try to inner join this view with a table, which contains 10 distinct dates, I was waiting to have 10 partitions from each table of the view  inner join this spool with the external table.

```
sel a.*
from viewa a
  inner join table_e b
   on a.cal_Date = b.cal_Date
```

it does an all amp retrieve from each table of the view and then duplicates the external table. The issue is that the 4 tables inside the view are very big, about 1 billion rows.

Solution for this?

I tried to make a volatile table (with one column =  date) which contains only the distinct date that I am expected but nothing. Still the same behaviour.

Comment: What statistics have been collected on the tables participating in this query? What are the primary index defintions of the tables being joined together? Are these views 1:1 with the base tables or do they perform joins as well? If the table with `10 distinct dates` is not partitioned or the primary index does not match the partitioned tables the redistribution required to join the spool files together and the ability for partition elimination may in fact be lost.

Answer (score 0):

Practically when you add "single table" condition to the view, the parser itself decides partition elimination based on the provided values.

```
sel * from viewa where cal_Date = '2013-05-31'
```

When you have "Join condition", parser has no way to find out what values are there in the other table, so it can be enhanced by dynamic partition elimination during run time but not static partition elimination as was the case above.

```
sel a.* from viewa a inner join table_e b on a.cal_Date = b.cal_Date
```

See if the following phrase comes in your explain "... join enhanced by dynamic partition elimination....". If not try partitioning table_e on cal_date with same partitioning expressions as other tables. It should help.

Comment: Than you for your reply.Unfortunately , there is no partition elimination .All the tables involved are partitioned on the cal_date and have the same PI ,except one. I tried even Soft RI but nothing. As i wrote in my first post , i tried to put all the needed values on a volatile table , but nothing. There is no way to force the dynamic partition elimination , like oracle hints(i know that they do not exist in Teradata ) in a way that i will rewrite the query?

Comment: The only solution that i found is to add one more filter where i will assign again the period that i want,  ......where cal_date between (function of teradata) and current_date..... Any other thoughts??? Thanks in advanve.